# How to handle a value that may be an std::string or std::wstring

Tags: c++, string, wstring

I have some code that reads a file and finds out whether it's Unicode or not. Depending on this I'd like to have a custom object that will hold the file contents as `wstring` or `string` and be able to do string manipulation.

I thought I could just have a base class with two derived classes representing wide and narrow strings or even a base class for `string` and one derived for `wstring`. Something like:

```
class CustomString
{
public:
   static CustomString *methodFactory(bool _unicode);
   std::string Value;

}

class NarrowString : public CustomString
{
public:
   SingleByte(std::string _value);
   std::string Value;
}

class WideString : public CustomString
{
public:
   WideString (std::wstring _value);
   std::wstring Value
}
```

What I'm having more difficulty with is the string manipulation methods, say I need `.replace`, `.length` and `.substr` how could I implement these? Would I need to use templates?

```
virtual T replace(size_t _pos, size_t _len, const T& _str);
```

Or have two methods for each type and override them in the derived classes?

```
virtual std::string replace(size_t _pos, size_t _len, const std::string& _str)
virtual std::wstring replace(size_t _pos, size_t _len, const std::wstring& _str)
```

An example of what the interface would look like using templates and no inheritance:

```
class CustomString
{
public:
    CustomString();
    CustomString(bool _unicode);

    template <typename T>
    T get();

    template <typename T>
    T replace(size_t _pos, size_t _len, const T& _str);

    long length();

    template <typename T>
    T substr(size_t _off);

    template <typename T>
    T append(const T& _str);

    template <typename T>
    T c_str();

private:
    std::wstring wValue;
    std::string nValue;
    bool unicode;

};
```

}

Comment: You need to use templates

Comment: I wouldn't write new classes. I would write generic code. That is you don't care if you have string or a wstring. All you care are the operations you can do on your object. Both classes support same operations.

Comment: Why not always hold the contents as wstring plus a flag that says whether the original was Unicode or not?

Comment: What is the *interface* to the custom object going to look like?

Comment: @MartinBonner when reading the file's contents there needs to be a cast to be able to store them in a string or wstring e.g. if 16bit characters; contents = ((wchar_t*)pData) where pData is a byte array (unsigned char)
I wouldn't be able to cast pData into a wstring if it was 8bit without some sort of conversion and these conversions can be problematic, specially in Windows

Comment: Yes, you need to convert, but I don't think it needs to be hard.  Just assign element by element.  For non-ASCII character (ignore EBCDIC for the moment) that probably won't get you the right wide character (depending on, eg, code page).  But if you remember to assign back to a narrow char before displaying, then all will be well.  We *really* need to know what the interface of your custom object is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. The custom object hasn't been created,my idea was to have something like the CustomString object in the question

Comment: Sorry.  Not clear.  I meant "what the interface of your custom object *is going to be*".

Comment: I've updated the questions with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest doing it in different form:

```
enum class Encoding{
   UTF8,
   UTF16
};

Encoding readFile(const char* path, std::string& utf8Result,std::wstring& utf16result);
```

now read the file to the correct object and return the correct encoding as result.
the use of this function can write generic code around this function with template generelization around `std::basic_string`:

```
template <class T>
void doNext(const std::basic_string<T>& result){/*...*/}

std::string possibleUTF8Result;
std::wstring possibleUTF16Result;
auto res = readFile("text.txt",possibleUTF8Result,possibleUTF16Result);
if (res == Encoding::UTF8){
  doNext(possibleUTF8Result);
} else { doNext(possibleUTF16Result); }
```

*note: wstring is utf16 on windows but utf32 on linux.